# How to handle multiple error boundarie components using componentDidCatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm struggling dealing with multiple error boundaries.

Let me explain with some context:

**App.js**

```
<ErrorBoundary level="app">
  <SomeComponents>
    {/* ... */}
    <BuggyComponent/>

    <ErrorBoundary level="local">
       <NestedBuggyComponent/>
    </ErrorBoundary>

    {/* ... */}

  </SomeComponents>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

**ErrorBoundary.js**

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log('ErrorBoundary triggered at level: ' + this.props.level);
    this.setState({
      error,
      errorInfo
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { children, level } = this.props;
    const { error, errorInfo } = this.state;
    if (errorInfo) {
      return <div>An error detected at level: {level}</div>;
    }

    return children;
  }
}
```

With this following context, I'm looking to do this :

If `NestedBuggyComponent` throws an error and `BuggyComponent` do not, it should display:

```
<div>
  <div>{...}</div>

  <div>An error detected at level: local</div>

  <div>{...}</div>
</div>
```

But actually I have:

```
<div>An error detected at level: app</div>
```

which means it has been catched by top level `ErrorBoundary` with props `level="app"`

If one of my component crash, it must be catch by the nearest `ErrorBoundary` parent.

1. For `NestedBuggyComponent` component, it must be catch by `ErrorBoundary` with props `level="local"` and other components still should be displayed

   - It doesn't work ❌
2. For `BuggyComponent` component, it must be catch by `ErrorBoundary` with props `level="app"` and just an error should be displayed

   - It works ✅

Any suggestion on **how to solve criteria n°1** ?